# Probability using rainfall data

Tags: probability, statistics

I stuck on this problem. Please help me to solve it out.
A study of rainfall data at a station in July based on many years observation has shown that:
Probability of a rainy-rainy day(i.e  a rainy day following a rainy day) is 0.444, a dry-dry day is 0.724, a dry-rainy day is 0.276. a rainy-dry day is 0.556. I t is observed that a certain July day is rainy. What is the probability the next two day will also be rainy?

Comment: What are your own thought about this problem? Have you tried something?

Comment: You will have to make some assumption about independence.  In real life, presumably, the probability of one rainy day following another will go down as the string of rainy days increases.  That is, if we've had several rainy days in a row the probability of rain starts to decline (some version of the Gambler's Fallacy is probably true in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given certain assumptions as lulu mentioned, your problem is describing a 2-state Markov process (you can find a lot of material online, Wikipedia is a great place to start).

You are given the conditional probabilities that the next day will be rainy or dry, based on the current day's weather. Let's denote a rainy day as $R$, dry day as $D$, and the probability of an event as $P(x|y)$, where $x$ is the next day's weather and $y$ is the current weather.

Your data is summarized as follows:

$P(R|R) = 0.444 \hspace{1cm} P(R|D) = 0.276$

$P(D|R) = 0.556 \hspace{1cm} P(D|D) = 0.724$

Notice how the columns add up to 1 but not necessarily the rows, convince yourself that this should be the case. Also, notice that the probability of a day's weather only depends on the previous day's weather, and so the probability of a series of days is simply the product of the probabilities for each day.

I find that it's helpful to try to visualize things. This tree diagram shows you all the possible realizations of the next two day's weather, given the initial day was rainy. The initial day is on top, the following day is the next row, and the final day is on the bottom.

[image]

For example, to calculate if the next two days will be dry, given today is rainy, we get $P(DD) = P(D|R)P(D|D) = 0.556*0.724 \approx 0.403$. Try solving for your specific question.

Hope this helps!